# How do I print a string while drawing a circular spiral in Python-turtle?

Tags: python, string, python-turtle

I want a turtle program that prints out letters while drawing a circular spiral in a counterclockwise direction.
I know how to print out while drawing a circle, but I want to know how to implement a circular spiral.

Given the following code :

```
import random
import math
from tkinter.simpledialog import *

inStr = ''
swidth, sheight = 500, 500
tX, tY, txtSize = 0,0,20
radius, angle, radian = 200, 0, 0

turtle.title('turtle spiral string')
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.setup(width = swidth + 50, height = sheight + 50)
turtle.screensize(swidth, sheight)   
turtle.penup()

inStr = askstring('inputstring', 'Enter string to write turtle')

angle = 360*2 / len(inStr)

for ch in inStr :
   
    radian = 3.14 * angle / 180
    
    tX = radius * math.cos(radian)
    tY = radius * math.sin(radian)
    r = random.random(); g = random.random(); b = random.random()
    
    turtle.goto(tX, tY)
     
    turtle.pencolor((r, g, b))
    turtle.write(ch, font=('Malgun Gothic', txtSize, 'bold'))

    angle += 360*2/ len(inStr)

turtle.done()
```

**Code Results**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzalc.png)

**Expected Results**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYR1k.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach would be to increase the radius slightly on each character iteration as you advance the angle slightly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sin, cos, radians
from random import random

swidth, sheight = 500, 500
txtSize = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.title('turtle spiral string')
screen.setup(width=swidth + 50, height=sheight + 50)
screen.screensize(swidth, sheight)

string = screen.textinput('inputstring', 'Enter string to write turtle')

length = len(string)
angle = 0
theta = 360 / length
radius = delta = swidth/2 / length

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.penup()

for character in string:
    radian = radians(angle)
    tX = radius * cos(radian)
    tY = radius * sin(radian)

    turtle.goto(tX, tY)

    turtle.pencolor(random(), random(), random())
    turtle.write(character, font=('Malgun Gothic', txtSize, 'bold'))

    angle += theta
    radius += delta

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.mainloop()
```

[image]